# How to log site users in to another site

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, http-headers

I have a website and my users log in to my site. For each user, I store their credentials to another third-party site. I would like to be able to log the user in to the third-party site from within my site (preferable) or in a new tab (less preferable).

The problem is that the third-party site uses the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN` header. Is there any way I can achieve this if I have my users' credentials for the third-party site?

Comment: I hope you aren't storing their logins and passwords to other sites...?

Comment: The facet that they have sameorigin policy in place means that they do not want anyone to be able to login from not the same origin.

Comment: @derekmckinnon it is my account on the other site and I am creating the sub-accounts for them and storing those credentials in my database

Comment: @blizz Ahh ok. Something I've seen done before includes acting as a proxy server for the target site. It requires intercepting the HTML, injecting values, and submitting the login form. Not for the faint of heart, and it can be broken if the target changes their app enough...this is why things like SSO and OAuth are nicer.

Comment: @derekmckinnon I understand...sounds like an unreliable solution. Just out of curiosity, do you have any guide that explains how to implement that? Thanks!

Comment: @blizz Unfortunately I do not have a guide handy but what I can tell you is that you will need to wire up an HttpClient and essentially rewrite parts of the page such that all URLs and javascript events are proxied to your application and then your app passes them to the target. I've seen it done in PHP...not .NET but the concepts are the same. I can put together a gist showing how to override the Javascript side of things. Hacky as hell though...

Comment: @blizz: here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/derekmckinnon/451865c8fd455822340dd9b3f930a50e) with the XMLHttpRequest hackery. I make no guarantees that this will work exactly for your use case, but maybe it will help in some way

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments what you are looking for is **Single Sign On (SSO)**

> Single Sign On (SSO) occurs when a user logs in to one application and is then signed in to other applications automatically, regardless of the platform, technology, or domain the user is using.

Source: https://auth0.com/docs/sso/current

**Security Note**

For security reasons you should not try to roll your own solution. See all the data breaches that happen every day and the heavy GDPR fines for who fails to protect user data. Plus Broken Authentication is in the [OWASP top 10-2017](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A2-Broken_Authentication)